# How can I set an API key, which contains equal sign set at Drush site-install?

Tags: drush

When I use the drush site-install command and a form value contains the equal sign (an API key for example), then Drush cuts the value at the equal sign. For example:

> drush si -y profile_name
>        --account-name=...
>        --account-pass=...
>        --db-url=mysql:...
>        form_name.field_name="e+gklgfssdk=jgfsfg/11iXP6VJM0MjDpRk2MEKyc="

The value of the form_name.field_name at install will be "e+gklgfssdk", the last characters are missing, Drush cuts the value at the equal sign. This is a bug? Or how can I set the correct value?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there isn't a way to do this, actually. The site installation code splits the string on the '=' and doesn't do any unescaping nor does it look like it would support this. I haven't tried `escape()`ing the value and then passing it in (so that `=` would become `%3D`) but unless you were expecting an escaped value this would probably still not work.

Depending on what you're setting, your best bet might be to do some sort of `drush variable-set` and set the values after the site install completes.

Comment: It does not work, the result is: e+gklgfssdk\

Comment: Thanks, then this is a bug, I reported on github (drush-ops/drush).

Comment: In my case I can not avoid, the installation process must set an API key, which contains an equal sign. I hacking my Distribution temporarly.